# After Insert and SaveChanges getting old identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table with an `Id` column which is set to `Identity`. Now, when I am inserting record in a loop i.e.

```
foreach (int i in array)
{
    using (var entities = new myEntities())
    {
            TableA obj = new TableA();
            obj.Name = "MyName";
            obj.Address = "MyAddress";
            entities.TableA.Add(obj);
            isAdded = entities.SaveChanges() > 0;

            if (isAdded)
            {
                 int id = obj.Id;
                 obj.IdInString = id.ToString();
                 entities.SaveChanges();
            }
    }
}
```

Now, for the first iteration it brings correct Id. But for second iteration it still brings back the id of first row inserted. Whereas I can see in the DB that second row is inserted and ID is incremented too.

What is going on? What am I doing wrong here?
EDIT:
I came back to this issue after some time and found that this is NOT to do with loop. It is returning old ID even when I come to the page next time. It seems it is getting cached. I have already used entity inside "using" block which means it is getting destroyed. 
Please note this is used in ASP.Net web application
Thanks..

Comment: What is the Id of the row that gets inserted?

Comment: i is never used inside the loop. Might need to see more code to know what's going on with myEntities and TableA

Comment: @CodeCaster: the Id in the If column gets inserted correctly i.e. 1, 2 ,3 but IdInString is correct only for first row.

Comment: Tested your code, its working fine for me. New Id on each iteration. Share your table schema.

Comment: Better option is not to do this altogether. Use a computed column that returns `Id` as string. Nevertheless, it's interesting to know why the `Id` isn't returned correctly. Is this SQL Server?

Comment: @Kashif Replying after long time. I was on other issue. Coming back to this issue. This is not because of loop. ID is getting inserted correctly in DB, but after SaveChanges, when I inspect the ID, it is old one. It gets the value which was loaded probably when it started for the first time. I am using context inside "Using" block. Any thoughts?